# ASP.NET Website - How to construct a Web Service for a Web Forms Website

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

I have an ASP.NET Web Forms Website that is running .NET 4.0.  I have a simple search page that I want to pass filter criteria to a web service that will return JSON to the page.  I will ideally be executing a GET request from jQuery to the web service.

Using ASP.NET MVC, it is pretty straight forward to create a controller action that returns JSON, however, I have no idea no how to do this in  a ASP.NET Web Forms Website.  How do I do create a web service in ASP.NET Web forms that returns JSON that I can simply call via AJAX?

Just give me the JSON!

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy,  watch this video (it should be enough to get you started):

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-and-call-a-simple-web-service-in-aspnet

And read this:

http://scriptionary.com/2011/03/25/returning-json-from-an-asp-net-web-service/